# Delonghi Magnifica - pump stops after 10 seconds with fault lights

Tags: espresso-machine, bean-to-cup

My Delonghi Magnifica ECAM22.110.B Bean-to-Cup machine just stopped working. The symptoms are:

1. Machine starts as normal
2. Grinder runs and pump runs for exactly 10 seconds then cuts out
3. Water from steam nozzle also runs for exactly 10 seconds and then cuts out
4. On the machine, the "water" light is illuminated and the "fault" and "grounds" lights are flashing

Answer (score 2):

Given that this fault showed with hot water from the steam nozzle, I was guessing a pump or flow sensor fault. It turned out to be the flow sensor.

To repair:

1. Unplug the coffee machine from the mains
2. Remove the back panel, see [here](https://fr.ifixit.com/Guide/DeLonghi+ESAM+3000.B+Magnifica+Open/98952?lang=en) for instructions
3. Locate the flow sensor:

[image]

4. Unplug the electrical connection
5. Disconnect the two tubes (noting which goes where)
6. Remove the flow sensor
7. Carefully twist the top and bottom to open it
8. Rinse to remove any particles - mine had some coffee grounds in it which were probably jamming the mechanism
9. Carefully reassemble the sensor and reattach it
10. Replace the covers